# SQL Query not returning the largest

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a question. I keep trying a query to get the largest part used in a project but it is showing multiples. So for P1 it should only show Nut 700, and P6 should only show Cog 500

The query used is:

```
SELECT Distinct t1.J#, t1.P#, t1.pname, MAX(t1.qty) AS Most_Used 
FROM ((SELECT J#, P.P#, P.pname, qty 
FROM SPJ, P 
WHERE (P.P# = SPJ.P#) 
GROUP BY P.pname, J#, P.P#, SPJ.QTY)) t1
GROUP BY t1.J#, t1.P#, t1.Pname;
```

But I keep this answer:

```
J#  P#  pname   Most_Used
j1  p1  Nut     200
j1  p3  Screw   400
j3  p3  Screw   200
j3  p6  Cog     300
j4  p1  Nut     700
j4  p2  Bolt    100
j4  p3  Screw   500
j4  p4  Hammer  800
j4  p5  Cam     400
j4  p6  Cog     500
j5  p3  Screw   600
j5  p5  Cam     500
j6  p3  Screw   400
j7  p3  Screw   800
j7  p5  Cam     100
j7  p6  Cog     300
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a row_number() partitioned by J# and ordered by qty desc, and then get only the row_number = 1;

```
with rn as
(
    select     J#, P.P#, P.pname, qty, 
               row_number() over (partition by J# order by qty desc) as rnum
    from       SPJ
    inner join P
    on    P.P# = SPJ.P#
)
SELECT J#, P#, name, qty as MostUsed
FROM   rn
WHERE  rnum = 1;
```